# Using the class sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering with parameter affinity='precomputed'

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I'm having trouble understanding a specific use case of the `sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering` class as outlined in the official documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering). Say I want to use my own affinity matrix to perform clustering. I first instantiate an object of class `SpectralClustering` as follows:

```
from sklearn.clustering import SpectralClustering

cl = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=5,affinity='precomputed')
```

The documentation for the `affinity` parameter above is as follows:

> affinity : string, array-like or callable, default ‘rbf’
>
> If a string, this may be one of ‘nearest_neighbors’, ‘precomputed’, ‘rbf’ or one of the kernels supported by sklearn.metrics.pairwise_kernels.
>   Only kernels that produce similarity scores (non-negative values that increase with similarity) should be used. This property is not checked by the clustering algorithm.

Now the object `cl` has a method `fit` for which the documentation about its sole parameter `X` is as follows:

> X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>
> OR, if affinity==`precomputed`, a precomputed affinity matrix of shape (n_samples, n_samples)

This is where it gets confusing. I am using my own affinity matrix, where a measure of 0 means two points are identical, with a higher number meaning two points are more dissimilar. However, the other choices for the parameter `affinity` actually take a data set and produce a *similarity* matrix, for which *higher* values are indicative of more similarity, and *lower* values indicate dissimilarity (such as the radial basis kernel).

So when using the `fit` method on my instance of `SpectralClustering`, do I actually need to transform my affinity matrix into a similarity matrix before passing it to the `fit` method call as the parameter `X`? The same documentation page makes a note on transforming distance to well-behaved similarities, but does not explicitly indicate where this step should should be carried out, and via which method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the docs:

> If you have an affinity matrix, such as a distance matrix, for which 0 means identical elements, and high values means very dissimilar elements, it can be transformed in a similarity matrix that is well suited for the algorithm by applying the Gaussian (RBF, heat) kernel:

```
np.exp(- X ** 2 / (2. * delta ** 2))
```

This goes in your own code, and the result of this can be passed to `fit`. For the purpose of this algorithm, affinity means similarity, not distance.

Comment: Thanks - I noticed that snippet, but was caught up on the wording, i.e. affinity meaning similarity, as opposed to distance.