# scikit-learn biclustering error: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a 24866-by-13 matrix of one's and zero's and wanted to discover biclusters from it. I tried sci-kit learn's [spectral co-clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralCoclustering.html#sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralCoclustering) and [spectral biclustering](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralBiclustering.html#sklearn.cluster.bicluster.SpectralBiclustering) but both of them return the error "ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs."

The matrix is stored as a NumPy array, and I verified that it indeed only contains one's or zero's and no infs or NaNs. The error messages for the spectral co-clustering are:

```
>>> RNAiDf = pd.read_table(dfFile, index_col=0)
>>> RNAiDf.head()
       HBEC30  H1155  HCC366  H1819  HCC44  HCC4017  H1993  H460  H2073  \
22848       1      0       0      0      0        1      0     0      0   
9625        0      0       0      0      0        0      0     0      0   
25          0      0       1      0      0        0      0     0      0   
27          0      0       0      0      0        0      0     0      0   
10188       0      0       1      0      0        0      0     0      1   

       H2009  H2122  H1395  HCC95  
22848      0      1      0      0  
9625       0      1      0      0  
25         0      0      0      1  
27         0      0      0      0  
10188      1      0      0      0  
>>> RNAiMatrix = RNAiDf.values
>>> RNAiMatrix.shape
(24866, 13)
>>> model = bicluster.SpectralCoclustering()
>>> model.fit(RNAiMatrix)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 122, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 271, in _fit
    u, v = self._svd(normalized_data, n_sv, n_discard=1)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 135, in _svd
    **kwargs)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 296, in randomized_svd
    Q = randomized_range_finder(M, n_random, n_iter, random_state)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 229, in randomized_range_finder
    Q, R = linalg.qr(Y, mode='economic')
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_qr.py", line 127, in qr
    a1 = numpy.asarray_chkfinite(a)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 668, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

and for the spectral biclustering:

```
>>> model = bicluster.SpectralBiclustering()
>>> model.fit(RNAiMatrix)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 122, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 440, in _fit
    u, v = self._svd(normalized_data, n_sv, n_discard)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster.py", line 135, in _svd
    **kwargs)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 296, in randomized_svd
    Q = randomized_range_finder(M, n_random, n_iter, random_state)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 229, in randomized_range_finder
    Q, R = linalg.qr(Y, mode='economic')
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_qr.py", line 127, in qr
    a1 = numpy.asarray_chkfinite(a)
  File "/work/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 668, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

The error seems to stem from computing the QR decomposition of some matrix. The parameter for setting the number of biclusters doesn't seem to make any difference. I am using scikit-learn version 0.16.1, and none of the columns are constant. Any tips on what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide example data ad code.

Comment: Also, which version of scikit-learn are you using? Because in current master branch this randomized_range_finder function was changed a little bit. Maybe update on latest version will help.

Comment: Any constant columns maybe?

Comment: I'm using version 0.16.1, and none of the columns are constant. I've also updated my post to include code.

Comment: What happens if you call `RNAiDf = RNAiDf.dropna()` after reading?

Comment: @MaxNoe, the exact same error still occurs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

RNAiMatrix should be a affinity matrix which "0" reprensents that two elements are the same, I think you'd better modify this matrix, and you can follow this
[Using the class sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering with parameter affinity='precomputed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530804/using-the-class-sklearn-cluster-spectralclustering-with-parameter-affinity-prec)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll be working on correcting the input matrix.