# KNN when using a precomputed affinity matrix in Scikit's spectral clustering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have a similarity matrix that I have calculated between a large number of objects, and each object can have a non-zero similarity with any other object. I generated this matrix for another task, and would now like to cluster it for a new analysis.

It seems like [scikit's spectral clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering) method could be a good fit, because I can pass in a precomputed affinity matrix. I also know that spectral clustering typically uses some number of nearest neighbors when building the affinity matrix, and my similarity matrix does not have that same constraint.

If I pass in a matrix that allows any number of edges between nodes in the affinity matrix, will scikit limit each node to having only a certain number of nearest neighbors? If not, I guess I will have to make that change to my pre-computed affinity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compute the affinity yourself to do some spectral clustering, sklearn does that for you.

When you call `sc = SpectralClustering()`,, the `affinity` parameter allows you to chose the kernel used to compute the affinity matrix. `rbf` seems to be the kernel by default and doesn't use a particular number of nearest neighbours. However, if you decide to chose another kernel, you might want to specify that number with the `n_neighbours`parameter.

You can then use `sc.fit_predict(your_matrix)` to compute the clusters.

Comment: But I already have a similarity matrix that meets scikit's criteria (similarities are positive, is symmetrical, is square), and have been using the affinity='precomputed' option. Are you suggesting that I calculate a new affinity matrix based on my precomputed affinity matrix?

Comment: I guess you can compute your own affinity matrix if you want to but using your similarity matrix is enough (a similarity matrix is also suqare, positive and symmetrical). If your input data is a similarity matrix, let sklearn do the work for you, it will compute the affinity matrix by itself :)

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. I'm using a precomputed affinity matrix because it is the output of another resource intensive process. I am just trying to see if I can build something new out of the work that the previous process has already put in. The affinity matrix that I am handed to work with is substantially smaller than the input that was used to create it.

Comment: Ok, you said that you had a similarity matrix, that's why! Note that implementing spectral clustering from scratch using numpy/scipy is less than 10 lines of code and efficient as well!

Comment: Have a look there as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530804/using-the-class-sklearn-cluster-spectralclustering-with-parameter-affinity-prec?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Spectral clustering does not require a sparsified matrix.

But if I'm not mistaken it's faster to find the dmallest non-zero Eigenvectors of a sparse matrix rather than of a dense matrix. Worst case may remain O(n^3) though - spectral clustering is one of the slowest methods you can find.